# Simple JavaScript Rental Calculation

Tags: javascript, html

Hello Stack Overflowers.  I have an on going assignment in my HTML class. I currently have already created 4 simple intro pages for it but currently stuck on this very simple JavaScript calculation. I feel like I am close however. Please excuse my messy code. I am by all means of the term a "noob" at JS, but I am trying. Any help is appreciated.

**My prompt is to:**
"Create a page to allow the choice of an equipment from a short list and then allow selections of rental starting date and ending date and then calculate the number of days between the 2 selected dates. Finally, multiply the unit rental cost with the number of days and add 8% tax for the total cost."

My Code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> Rental Program </title>

<script language="javascript">

//listbox.htm

function processit() {
string1=document.myform.numb1.value;

numb2=document.myform.alist.selectedIndex;

perweek=0;

if (string1 == 'Books') { perweek=300; }
if (string1 == 'Calculator') { perweek=200; }
if (string1 == 'Computer') { perweek=100; }
if (string1 == 'Camera') { perweek= 50; }

}
</script>

</head>

<body

<form name=myform>
<h4>Enter the item you wish to rent using the list below:
<input size =12 type="text" name="numb1">
</h4>
<li> Books = $300 per week
<li> Calculator = $200 per week
<li> Computer = $100 per week
<li> Camera = $50 per week

<h4> Select how many weeks you wish to rent: </h4>


<p>

</form>

</body>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  
function GetDays(){
var dropdt = new Date(document.getElementById("drop_date").value);
var pickdt = new Date(document.getElementById("pick_date").value);
return parseInt((dropdt - pickdt) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
}

function cal(){
if(document.getElementById("drop_date")){
document.getElementById("numdays2").value=GetDays();
}  
function GetTotal(){
var total = ($('[numb1]').val()(*0.8*total));

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="reserve_form">

<div id="pickup_date"><p><label class="form">Pickup Date:</label><input type="date" class="textbox" id="pick_date" name="pickup_date" onchange="cal()"</p></div>

<div id="dropoff_date"><p><label class="form">Dropoff Date:</label><input type="date" class="textbox" id="drop_date" name="dropoff_date" onchange="cal()"/></p></div>

<div id="numdays"><label class="form">Number of days:</label><input type="text" class="textbox" id="numdays2" name="numdays"/></div>
<h5>Total Amount in $ </h5>
<input size =12 type="text" name="total">
<p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: me think this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Please can you be a little more specific about where you are stuck?

Comment: Hey @user230910 I am unsure on how to get the calculation to produce the "Total Amount in $" My calculation "var total = ($('[numb1]').val()(*0.08*total));" does not return a value.

Answer (score 1):

Error on line number 70. You also forgot to terminate the if statement

```
if(document.getElementById("drop_date")){
```

WORKING CODE:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Rental Program </title>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">

      //listbox.htm

      function processit() {
        string1=document.getElementById("numb1").value;

        //numb2=document.myform.alist.selectedIndex;

        perweek=0;

        if (string1 == 'Books') { perweek=300; }
        if (string1 == 'Calculator') { perweek=200; }
        if (string1 == 'Computer') { perweek=100; }
        if (string1 == 'Camera') { perweek= 50; }
return perweek
      }
    </script>

  </head>

  <body

<form name=myform>
  <h4>Enter the price of the item you wish to rent using the list below:
    <input size =12 type="text" name="numb1" id="numb1">
  </h4>
  <li> Books = $300 per week
  <li> Calculator = $200 per week
  <li> Computer = $100 per week
  <li> Camera = $50 per week

    <h4> Select how many weeks you wish to rent: </h4>


    <p>

  </form>

  </body>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var items = {
"Book":"300"
}
      function GetDays(){
        var dropdt = new Date(document.getElementById("drop_date").value);
        var pickdt = new Date(document.getElementById("pick_date").value);
        return parseInt((dropdt - pickdt) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
      }

      function cal(){
        if(document.getElementById("drop_date")){
        var result = GetDays()
        if(isNaN(result)){result="Please fill out both dates"}
          document.getElementById("numdays2").value=result;
          }
        }  
        function GetTotal(){
        var price = processit(document.getElementById("numb1").value)
        var duration = document.getElementById("numdays2").value
          var total = Math.floor((price*(0.8*(duration)))*100)/100;
          if(isNaN(total)){total="Please fill out both dates"}
document.getElementById("total").value = total
        }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="reserve_form">

      <div id="pickup_date"><p><label class="form">Pickup Date:</label><input type="date" class="textbox" id="pick_date" name="pickup_date" onchange="cal();GetTotal()"/></p></div>

      <div id="dropoff_date"><p><label class="form">Dropoff Date:</label><input type="date" class="textbox" id="drop_date" name="dropoff_date" onchange="cal();GetTotal()"/></p></div>

      <div id="numdays"><label class="form">Number of days:</label><input type="text" class="textbox" id="numdays2" name="numdays" disabled/></div>
      <h5>Total Amount in $ </h5>
      <input size =12 type="text" name="total" id="total" disabled>
      <p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm, thank you, I think you're right, but it still doesn't return a value for "Total Amount"

Comment: Got it. Check it out. BTW, you do not ever want people to be able to make changes to something used in your calculations. I disabled the "total days"  and the "total" inputs. Prevents some falsification. @EricaMorris

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Yeah, an output shouldn't have an option for input.

Comment: I ran the code, but I am still getting a syntax error at the "Total" . Am I using undefined variables or illogically mixing strings and integers? I looked through it and didn't see any signs of that however.

Comment: I did not edit your question. Copy my code and paste it, and it will work.  @EricaMorris

Comment: https://ibb.co/k4JR07 (The "NaN" error I received when I ran your code) Could this be due to not converting the strings for the equipment into  integers before calculating the total?

Comment: "NaN" is simply place holding and could be fixed. I do not consider "NaN" an error, for your information. If you desire that changed, I will do that. @EricaMorris

Comment: It has been fixed to say "Please fill out both date fields". @EricaMorris

Comment: And to answer your question about the "NaN", it is not because of the conversion of strings. The DOM is smart enough to know that if the `value` or `innerHTML` of an element consists of a number and only 1 number, it returns a number object. @EricaMorris

Comment: https://ibb.co/hFmznn Hmm, now it seems to be returning a couple of syntax errors.

Comment: Curse me.. I forgot a clsosing }! @EricaMorris

Comment: Done. @EricaMorris

Comment: https://ibb.co/bXLBYS It seems the total amount is defaulting to "Please enter both dates.." even when both dates are entered. Shouldn't the logic be  if(isNaN(total)){total=total} instead of  if(isNaN(total)){total="Please fill out both dates"} @TheManWhoMade

Comment: On my side it is showing the correct amount... @EricaMorris

Comment: Really? Weird. I cleared my cache and switched browsers, and it still is only compiling the date, not the Total Amount @TheManWhoMade.

Comment: give me another screenshot @EricaMorris

Comment: https://ibb.co/ihvgHn  "Books" is the input for the item. @TheManWhoMade

Comment: ... you will have to put the price of the item. Sorry. I should have told you that. @EricaMorris

Comment: I think I fixed it... @EricaMorris

Comment: Wait. Is `processit` ever being used? @EricaMorris

Comment: Hmm, can you explain? https://ibb.co/hcA3V7 It still isnt showing the Total after adding the price. I also thought I declared the price when encoding " if (string1 == 'Books') { perweek=300; }" @TheManWhoMade

Comment: I think i got it. I found that function if(string1==... i used it.@EricaMorris Look again at my answer

Comment: Yes! That was the issue! Thanks a ton.

Comment: https://ibb.co/eCcmHn Whoops, small logical error. The output for Books should return $324 but its returning $240. I think there was a miscalculation. @TheManWhoMade

Comment: Simply adding the price onto it fixed. Thank you! @TheManWhoMade